# Android's SensorManager fails to effectively unregister listeners

Tags: android

My app creates a `Service` that overrides onStartCommand to create a `SensorManager` and attach a `SensorEventListener` to one of the sensors:

```
public class AccelerometerService extends Service {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private SensorEventListener activeListener; 
    // ...

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        // ...

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        activeListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                Log.i("PluckLock", "" + event.values[0]);
            }
        };

        sensorManager.registerListener(activeListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SyntaxBlitz/PluckLock/blob/master/src/net/syntaxblitz/plucklock/AccelerometerService.java).

I want to override `Service`'s `onDestroy()` method and, in it, kill the sensor:

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(activeListener);
```

But when I do this, nothing actually happens! My `onSensorChanged()` listener **continues to receive correct values** from the accelerometer (or software LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor, in my case). The problem, of course, is quoted here in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html):

> Always make sure to disable sensors you don't need, especially when your activity is paused. Failing to do so can drain the battery in just a few hours.

My app only needs to ping the accelerometer for as long as the screen is actually unlocked. I've implemented (and verified the correct function of) `BroadcastReceiver`s that destroy the `Service` when the phone is locked, successfully calling its `onDestroy()` method. But nothing actually happens once I try to unregister the listeners.

I've found a few others asking this question, with no resolution.

- [Unregistering SensorManager doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071035/unregistering-sensormanager-doesnt-work)
- [How to unregister a listener from a sensor after stopping the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750742/how-to-unregister-a-listener-from-a-sensor-after-stopping-the-service)
- [SensorEventListener not unregistering itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947910/sensoreventlistener-not-unregistering-itself)
- [Android sensor listener does not get unregistered or sensor still retrieves values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239949/android-sensor-listener-does-not-get-unregistered-or-sensor-still-retrieves-valu)
- [SensorEventListener doesn't get unregistered with unregisterListener() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919577/sensoreventlistener-doesnt-get-unregistered-with-unregisterlistener-method)

I can only assume it is an API bug, and that there is really no good way to kill these sensors once I've started grabbing data from them. I have tried setting the `SensorManager`, `Sensor`, and `SensorEventListener` to null, as well as trying to register a null sensor listener with the manager. None of these have any effect on the polling.

My current "workaround" has almost no effect on battery life. I have a private boolean in my class's definition that I set to `true` or `false` depending on whether I want sensor values. In my `onSensorChanged()` method, I immediately `return` if the sensor listener is supposed to be inactive. But by then, it is too late: the brunt of the work being performed by the OS (getting sensor values) occurs before I can manage to leave the `onSensorChanged()` method, so battery life is still horrendous for as long as my service is running.

My real question here, barring some miracle *real* solution, is **what can I do to stop getting sensor values?** Obviously, unregistering the sensor listener does not work at this point; even setting everything to null and destroying the service has no effect. But there must be *some* way to indicate to the operating system that my app doesn't require use of the sensor values anymore. Is there some way to kill my entire app, only restarting it when the phone is unlocked? Maybe that would let the operating system know that my app's not in need of values anymore. Really, any solution that legitimately stops polling the sensor but gives me some way to restart it, even if the code is ugly, would make me happy.

The minimum API level for my project is 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue.

Workaround to stop the sensor from draining the battery.

I used a static boolean `mIsSensorUpdateEnabled`. Set it to 'false' when you want to stop getting values from sensors. 
And in onSensorChanged() method, check the value of the boolean variable and again make to call to unregister the sensors. And this time, it works. The sensors would be unregistered and you will no longer get onSensorChanged callback.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
        private static boolean mIsSensorUpdateEnabled = false;
        private SensorManager mSensorManager;
        private Sensor mAccelerometer;

        @override
        protected void onCreate(){
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        }

        private startSensors(){
            mAccelerometer =  mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            int delay = 100000; //in microseconds equivalent to 0.1 sec
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                        mAccelerometer,
                        delay
                );
            mIsSensorUpdateEnabled =true;
        }

        private stopSensors(){
             mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
             mIsSensorUpdateEnabled =false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (!mIsSensorUpdateEnabled) {
                stopSensors();
                Log.e("SensorMM", "SensorUpdate disabled. returning");
                return;
            }
            //Do other work with sensor data
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet, but when I do I'll be sure to mark your answer as accepted if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And finally I was able to enable the sensor reading by setting sensorManager object as null. So that sensorManager can not register any listener. And when you want to read the sensor data, call a startRegister method to define sensorManager object and listeners. Here is my code:

```
public class SensorReadingClass implements SensorEventListener {

    public SensorReadingClass(Service c){
        this.mContext=c;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (mSensorManager != null) {
            // list available sensors and power consumption
            List<Sensor> sensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        } else {
            if(DBG) Log.e(TAG, "Could not get SensorManager instance");
        }
    }

    public float getHeartRate(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Heart Rate return value: " + heartRate);
        return heartRate;
    }

    public void startSensorListeners() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startSensorListeners");

        if(mSensorManager==null){
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        }

        readSensors=true;

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        Log.d(TAG, "Sensor started: " + mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL));

    }

    public void stopSensorListeners() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopSensorListeners");

        if(mSensorManager!=null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            mSensorManager=null;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Sensor stoppped: " + mSensorManager);
        readSensors=false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            String key = event.sensor.getName();
            float values = event.values[0];
            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                accellerometerEvent++;                  // this is event counts when sensor changes, this counts all the events changings. It shouldnt be necessary though
                accellerometerSensor = values + " " + event.values[1] + " " + event.values[2] + " " + accellerometerEvent; // This is the string for value and seen event count.

            }

            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
                heartRateEvent++;
                heartRateSensor = values + " " + heartRateEvent;
                heartRate = values;

            }

            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
                stepCounterEvent++;
                stepCounterSensor = values + " " + stepCounterEvent;

            }

            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                gyroscopeEvent++;
                try {
                    gyroscopeSensor = values + " " + event.values[1] + " " + event.values[2] + " " + gyroscopeEvent;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }

            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

    @Override
    // since we will always capture the data whether it changes or not, we don't need this method
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        return;
    }

}
```